# SSRs Expressions Count T SQL Server 2008 Report builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, expression, report-builder2.0

1. List item

Hi I am trying to count the number of times an event is raised within the last 14 days of a date. simply put if i have an opened case on the 23rd of last month i want to check the previous 14 days of the 23rd to see if there have been another event raised of the same type within that period.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't do this in the SQL, and need to have it within the RDL?

The SQL should be easy, try making use of subqueries to get around the aggregate-of-an-aggregate hurdle.

If you need to do it within the RDL, the Lookup() and LookupSet() functions might make your life easier.

If this doesn't help you, could you post a bit more detail?  Data structure may help.

Comment: Hi Kyzen i have edited the SQL to include a field which will identify the weeks i have included my SQL if it helps to show what i am trying to achieve.